# Python find index of last element smaller than number

Tags: python, list, performance

I have a list of numbers from 0 to 3 and I want to remove every number that is smaller than 2 xor is not connected to the last 3 in the list. It is also going to be done about 200 Million times so it should preferably perform well. For example, I could have a list like that:

```
listIwantToCheck = [3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1]
listIWantToGet = [2, 3, 2, 2, 3]
```

I already have the index of the last 3 so what I would do is:

```
listIWantToGet = listIWantToCheck[??? : indexOfLastThree + 1]
```

??? being 4 in this instance. It is the index with the mentioned conditions.
So How do I get the index of the last number smaller than 2?

Comment: What do you mean about the `is not connected to the last 3 in the list`????

Comment: They are connected if they come before the last 3 are next to the it or another 2/3 which is either next to the last three or another 2/3 that is and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Nailed it, the index i want is

```
index = ([0]+[i for i, e in enumerate(listIWantToCheck[:indexOfLastThree]) if e < 2])[-1] + 1
```

List comprehension is truly beautiful.
I enumerated through the slice and created a list of all indices, which point to a number smaller than 2 and took the last. The 0 in front is added to circumvent an index error, which would occur if there are no elements smaller than 2.

Answer (score 0):

So if i get this right you want to get the index of the last number smaller than 2 that comes before the last 3.

My approach would be to take the part of the list from index 0 to the index of the last 3 and then reverse the list and check if the number is smaller than 2.

If you however want to get the last 2 of the entire list just reverse it and loop through it the same way

```py
for i in listIWanttoCheck[0:indexOfLastThree].reverse():
    if i <2:
        return listIWanttoCheck.index(i)
```

Correct me if I missunderstood your problem